# How can I determine the baud rate of my RFID reader?

Tags: windows, smartcard, rfid, baud-rate

When my RFID reader reads a tag, it shows me multiple information. I am aware that one tag is equivalent to one information. I believe that it is the baud rate. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks. The baud rate that I have set is 9600. I have a long range RFID reader by the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the baud rate set incorrectly, you would most likely see garbage text, not multiple entries.  The characters themselves would be corrupted.

Comment: Okay thanks. Well, about the multiple entries, what do you think is the problem? Thanks for the reply sir.

Comment: Hardware will ultimately decide, but either there will be hardware setting on the reader to filter out duplicate reads from a certain amount of time or you will have to implement your own duplicate filter after recording the read.